# How use Zabbix instead of ELK as an on-premise analytics solution for WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

It is the document for using ELK as an on-premise analytics solution for WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/

But I don't know how to use Zabbix instead of ELK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 supports ELK as an on-premise analytics solution by default. You can write a connector for a analytics solution of your choice (Zabbix in your case). For this, please follow this [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/).

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/